# How to intercept queries in a subclassed DBI?

Tags: perl, dbi

I need to intercept all queries (in order to, say, do some structered logging).
The app already uses a sub-classed DBI so I was hoping I could just inject the code I need in to the `execute` overload in `MyDB::st` class.

Apparently, this is not sufficient.

In the example below, `MyDB::st::execute` executes only in example 2). It does not execute in 1) where I call `do` nor in 3) where I call `selectrow_array` (even though the documentation says `selectrow_array` combines `prepare`, `execute`, and `fetchrow_hashref`).

Do I need to overload statements in `MyDB::db` class as well? There is quite a few (`do`, `selectrow_array`, `selectrow_arrayref`, `selectrow_hashref`, `selectall_arrayref`, `selectall_array`, `selectall_hashref`, `selectcol_arrayref`, etc.) I was hoping I could avoid that.

The example uses SQLite for simplicity but other drivers I checked worked the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyDB;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'DBI';

sub connect {
    return DBI::connect( 'MyDB', 'dbi:SQLite:dbname=so.sqlite', '', '',);
}


package MyDB::db;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'DBI::db';

sub prepare {
    my $self = shift;
    warn "  DB: PREPARE\n";
    return $self->SUPER::prepare( @_ );
}


package MyDB::st;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'DBI::st';

sub execute {
    my $self = shift;
    warn "  ST: EXECUTE\n";
    return $self->SUPER::execute( @_ );
}

sub fetchrow_hashref {
    my $self = shift;
    warn "  ST: FETCHROW_HASHREF\n";
    return $self->SUPER::fetchrow_hashref( @_ );
}




package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dbh = MyDB::connect();

warn "1) --- DO ---\n";
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ttt (a int)");

warn "2) --- PREPARE/EXECUTE/FETCHROW_HASHREF ---\n";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM ttt" );
$sth->execute();
$sth->fetchrow_hashref();

warn "3) --- SELECTROW_ARRAY ---\n";
$dbh->selectrow_array( "SELECT * FROM ttt" );
```

Comment: Best to say exactly what you're planning on doing because (for example), DBD::SQlite already comes with the ability to log statements, so there's no reason to intercept queries. IIRC it's something like `$dbh->sqlite_trace=1;`

Comment: `DBI` does some strange things with packages. I would much prefer to see simple wrappers for the operations that you need to hook into, rather than attempting to override inherited methods.

Comment: @ChrisTurner - I need to dump some data in a structured way (queries, execution times, some information about program state).

Answer (score 4):

While the documentation describes certain methods in terms of other methods, the documentation doesn't claim these method call those other methods.

Each driver provides their own implementation of many of the DBI methods (e.g. `selectrow_array`) through the use of a template provided by DBI. Written in C, the implementation of the methods in the template frequently call the driver's functions directly rather than calling them indirectly through DBI method calls.

This makes the calls faster, but as you've discovered, it makes it harder to extend DBI.

You can find a Perl implementation of all the methods you listed inside of `DBI.pm`. Copy these. These implementations are all defined in terms of the following methods, limiting what you have to change:

- `prepare`
- `execute`
- `fetch`
- `fetchrow_hashref`
- `fetchrow_arrayref`
- `bind_col`

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is log queries, you don't need to intercept anything.  Try setting the `DBI_TRACE` environment variable.

```
DBI_TRACE=1=dbitrace.log
```

where the `1` is the log level and the second argument is a path to your log file.  See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#DBI_TRACE and https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING

Comment: I know about `DBI_TRACE` but parsing the log is not really an option. I want to dump some structured data such as the query string, execution time, perl call stack, and some information about the program state.